# Read data from non-connectable BLE sensor?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I have a BLE thermometer and I'd like to record the data from it as the monitoring application (available for both Android and iOS) that comes with it doesn't do it, it merely displays the data on the screen for a limited time.

I tried all BLE apps on both Android (I have a Nexus5 with Android 4.4) and iOS 7.1 iPad with but, while some discovered the device, none of them could display any data because all try to *connect* to the sensor whereas the sensor returns 0 for `kCBAdvDataIsConnectable`.

Is this possible? It must be because its own app does it, but I'm not too familiar with BLE and I may be missing something. I was surprised that none of the apps in the App/Play store had the feature of "listening" what a device sends without connecting. But then again, I'm not very familiar with BLE.

A few pointers are appreciated.

Comment: My guess is that the device is just advertising the temperature with implementing the full GATT service. You may need to examine the advertising data to see if you can find the temperature

Comment: @Paulw11 You're right, it's using two bytes to send the data. You can post the suggestion as an answer and I'll mark it so.

Comment: @wishihadabettername yes, it would be putting the temperature data in the advertising packets which is pretty much the typical use case cited for BLE devices to be broadcast only. As suggested, please post a capture of the advertising packet data and it might be possible to then decode how its transmitting the temp data.

Comment: Hi.. I have same problem.. I am able to get discovered values but if i do same for multiple sensors it creates error.. please help if you can..